# Can I re-ask an old question that was only partially answered?

Tags: discussion

This is the question I'm asking about: [Input and Output binary streams using JERSEY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496209/input-and-output-binary-streams-using-jersey)

This was asked 4 years ago and has tons of votes.  The problem is, almost every answer is answering about returning streams, I don't see answers about passing in streams.  I only care about the latter.

1. Can I reword this question to be more accurate based on the answers?
2. Can I ask again about the half that I care about?

I'd like an answer to this question, but I don't think anyone will be adding it any time soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be editing the question to ask something different just because there are answerers that failed to answer the question properly (or completely).

If you ask a new question that isn't answered by this existing question's answers, then you're more than welcome to post the new question.  The fact that the questions have some overlap doesn't matter given that *the answers to that question wouldn't answer this question*.

The question may benefit from linking to the related question and explaining why the answers given fail to answer the question that you have.

You're more than welcome to answer the existing question with an answer that you feel is more complete or that addresses an aspect of the question not in other answers.

Comment: OK, but why would it be wrong to mark my new question as a duplicate?

Comment: @DanielKaplan If the answers on the proposed duplicate don't answer the question, then it wouldn't be a duplicate.

Comment: Interesting, I've been on this site for years and I thought that "duplicate" was in the context of questions, not in the context of "answers".  i.e., I assumed that if someone already asked a question that had 0 answers, you were technically in your rights to mark the new one as a duplicate.

Comment: You are not *able* to, even if you wanted to. (Unless you're a mod, or both questions were asked by the same user (to deal with double-postings)).

Answer (score 2):

Reading that question, I see nothing about passing streams. You said none of the answers would apply to that, so I'll take your word for it :).

All indicators to me indicate that your question as presented would not be a duplicate. Go ahead and ask, linking to that question if it provides context.

Comment: Well he said, "Retrieve multipart data, such some JSON plus an uploaded XLS file".  I assume he meant on the server.